# NodeJs Express post, error req.body undefined

Tags: node.js, express, post, undefined

My API can't find my post parameters.
This is code:

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var redis = require ('redis'); 
var tools = require('./Read');

var app = new express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

client= redis.createClient();   

app.get("/Json", function(req,res){
  let b = req.query.Menù;
  var secondomenu = new tools.Menu("secondo","secondo",2);
  var stringa="";
  var a = b.toString().split('p');

  let ciao =new tools.Menu(a[0],a[1],a[2]);
  let c =[];
  c.push(ciao);
  c.push(secondomenu);
  for (var i =0; i<c.length; i+=1)
  {
    stringa  +=  retMen(c[i]);
  }
  client.hset("hash key", "Menu1",JSON.stringify(c), redis.print);

  res.send(stringa);
});

app.post("/Save", function(res,req){
  var guid = req.body.guid;
  var idMenu = req.body.idMenu;
  var Menu = req.body.Menu;
  client.hset(guid, idMenu, Menu, redis.print);
  res.send("Tutto OK");
}) 

function retMen (Menu) {
  return (Menu.IdMenù+ "  "+ Menu.desc+ "  " +Menu.Vote);
};

app.listen(11100);
```

And this is the error

> Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:29026/e0f09df5-7d1d-4356-bec8-c2a4becabc96
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'guid' of undefined
>   application.js:630

Can someone help me?

Comment: Show how u r routing to `/save` . The html part

Comment: Your arguments in the save route are switched. It should be "app.post("/Save", function(**req**,res) {"

Comment: yes i had solved

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post("/Save", function(req,res)
{

var guid = req.body.guid;
var idMenu = req.body.idMenu;
var Menu = req.body.Menu;
client.hset(guid, idMenu, Menu, redis.print);
res.send("Tutto OK");
})
```

> req,res instead of res,req